# Javascript - Greedy regex issue

Tags: javascript, regex

My regex must match what's within /* @DT-HIDE */ and /* @/DT-HIDE */. It's fine until a page contains two blocks.

If there are two blocks, well, $1 will match all that's between the first opening @DT-HIDE and last @/DT-HIDE.
I suppose it's about a greedy * instead of an ? but I can't figure it out.

Regex:

```
const pattern = new RegExp(/(\/\*\s@DT-HIDE\s\*\/) ([\s\S]*?) (\/\*\s@\/DT-HIDE\s\*\/)/g);
```

Example value being processed:

```
/* @DT-HIDE */
function(){
    return "...";
}
/* @/DT-HIDE */

/* @DT-HIDE */
function logic(url){
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
        ...
    });
}
/* @/DT-HIDE */
```

Comment: Since you're using the `new RegExp()` constructor, it's a shame you don't pass it a string rather than a `/.../` construct : you would avoid having to escape slashes inside the regexp. You would instead need to escape double-quotes, which wouldn't be a problem in your case.

Comment: Well, that's already a good info - thanks for that!

Comment: Hah.. As I can see the only problem are the two spaces you have between the groups (between the brackets): `/(\/\*\s@DT-HIDE\s\*\/)([\s\S]*?)(\/\*\s@\/DT-HIDE\s\*\/)/g`. Also you don't need the constructor simply assign the regex to the `pattern` variable

Comment: @Aaron: double (or single) quotes but also all backslashes.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte right, although they already need to be escaped in `/.../` constructs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have had `[\s\S]*` in your original pattern, otherwise you would not obtain a "greedy" match.

However, as Slim noticed, the spaces you introduced failed the match since there is no space after `/* @DT-HIDE */`. So, you may solve the issue by removing the spaces. Declaring the pattern with a conbstructor notation is a good idea when your pattern contains many slashes, but in this case you may use a regex literal without the RegExp constructor:

```
const pattern = /(\/\*\s@DT-HIDE\s\*\/)([\s\S]*?)(\/\*\s@\/DT-HIDE\s\*\/)/g;
```

However, the pattern is not optimal, since the lazy dot matching patterns may involve many "forward-trackin" steps. I suggest [unrolling](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop) it as

```
const pattern = /(\/\*\s@DT-HIDE\s\*\/)([^\/]*(?:\/(?!\*\s@\/DT-HIDE\s\*\/)[^\/]*)*)(\/\*\s@\/DT-HIDE\s\*\/)/g;
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YgQFUf/2/).

The `[^\/]*(?:\/(?!\*\s@\/DT-HIDE\s\*\/)[^\/]*)*` will make matching more efficient especially if the number of `/` is not that big in between the delimiters.